# Period of pulsation of a star and its relation to free fall and acoustic waves

Tags: star, stellar-astrophysics

In [this paper](https://www.mps.mpg.de/phd/solar-physics-lecture-2007-helioseismology), the period $\Pi$ of pulsation for a star can be obtained by means of the virial theorem:

$$\Pi = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{sR^3}{(3\gamma - 4)qGM}}$$

where $s$ and $q$ are constants relating to the star and $\gamma = c_P/c_V$ is the ratio of specific heat capacities at constant pressure and volume. I would like to know how one can relate $\Pi$ to:

(a) the time of free fall

and

(b) the acoustic travel time

from the surface of the star to its center.

Comment: Please define all the symbols.

Comment: Done. I would appreciate a comprehensive answer to the two questions posed above

Comment: Check the paper I have provided at the beginning of the question for explicit definitions of q and s.

Comment: Write down a) and b) and divide them by $\Pi$? Or what else do you mean with 'relate'?